# Trying to perform an action after loading a javascript resource

Tags: javascript, jquery

Clicking a button on a page causes to a javascript file to be loaded. How do I call a function on the completion of the loaded file?

Comment: How do you load it? Can you show some code, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You can load the file using jQuery's `getScript()` function and then call a function from this script.

#### Sample

```
$.getScript('YourJavascriptFile.js', function() {
   // file is loaded
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can put a [$(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in the script file you are dynamically loading, which will execute as soon as the loading is complete (assuming the DOM it's being loaded into is already "ready")

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // save the world
});
```